# Alternatives for "Are you free now?”

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, american-english, british-english

I want to make a official call and ask the other person whether he is free or not at that particular time. I think asking, “Are you free now?” does't sound formal. So, are there any alternatives to it?

Comment: "Are you available?" "Are you available for a meeting/talk/etc." "Is now a good time?"

Comment: Asking first if you may speak about official business is both a waste of time and inviting excuses. Yes, it is polite and common, but all replacements are trouble. Can you not say, "Hello, this is Rajana, and I need to speak with about ABC"?

Answer (score 2):

**available**  [TDF](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/available)

1. Present and ready for use; at hand; accessible: kept a fire extinguisher available at all times.
2. Capable of being gotten; obtainable: a bedspread available in three colors.
3. Qualified and willing to serve or assist: a list of available candidates; was not available for comment.

You can consider:

> Are you available to speak at this time?

Answer (score 1):

A few might be "are you busy at the moment?", "Are you available?" or "are you occupied?"
Thanks